# Find the shortest path from s passing a multiple of 3 edges, in directed and unweighted graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be an `directed and unweighted` graph: `G=(V,E)`.
I want to find the shortest path from node `s` , `to all vertices with a multiple of 3 edges (arcs)`.

My idea was to build new graph,`G'`, which includes:
3 copies for each node in the original graph, called `v1,v2,v3`.
and for each edge (arc) `(u,v)` in the original graph, I will build 3 new edges in the new graph: `(u1,v2),(u2,v3),(u3,v1)`.
Then to use BFS algorithm that checks if there is a path passes from `v1` to `u1` and then it (maybe?) tells us that there is a path passes from s to through a multiple of 3 edges.
I am not sure that this is a solution to the problem.
Can someone help to fix my solution ?

Comment: Your solution sounds perfect to me. It takes 3 edges to get back to v1 and all possible paths are represented.

Comment: I am not sure since I thought maybe we need to add  a condition to check if d[w]mod2==0 (where w is a neighbor of some vertex in G' which we run with for loop) and then return the BFS-tree with the edge that connects w with this vertex (and this should be therefore multiple of 3 edges). shouldn't er add such condition?

Comment: All paths that end on a node in `v1` will have a length that is a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is a path that passes through 3N edges ( v1, v2, v3, .... v(3n+1) ) then the shortest path that passes through a multiple of 3 edges will be ( v1, v2, v3, v4 ).

Do a depth fist search keeping count of distance from source.  Stop when a distance of 3 edges is reached.  If all nodes visited and no stop, then no such path exists.